# Is it possible to have a dash rangeslider without marks EXCEPT for the currently selected min and max?

Tags: plotly-dash

I need a range slider with a minimum of 0 and a maximum of ~23800 with a small step size (max 100). Is it possible to show only the minimum, maximum and the currently selected minimum and maximum marks (i.e. just 4 marks as opposed to ~238+)? I've read [the docs](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/rangeslider) but can't seen an option to achieve this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show only the marks at the beginning and at the end. Then use a tooltipo to always display the current value.

```py
import dash
from dash import html, dash, dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    dcc.Slider(
        min=0, max=23800, step=100,
        marks={0: '0', 23800: '23800'},
        tooltip={"placement": "bottom", "always_visible": True}
    )
)

app.run_server(debug=True)
```